# how can I make the files in initrd visible after casper mount?

Tags: boot, initrd

after casper mount the entire / gets replaced, thus the files generated by /init or other scripts in initrd will disappear. How can I make those file visible after logging into live system?

I can edit any file in initrd if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to access the initramfs root filesystem after the real root filesystem has been mounted.  Are there specific files generated in the initramfs that you are trying to access?  Since you mentioned *casper* I am assuming you are booting a live-cd image.

If you have access to the console then you can pause the boot process before the real root filesystem is mounted.  For example, adding the kernel argument `break=bottom` will pause the boot process before the real root filesystem is mounted and open a rescue shell in the initramfs environment.

If there are specific files you are interested in, (by default) contents of `/run/initramfs` will persist between the initramfs environment and the booted environment.  Certain log files are written there.  You might be able to add a hook to copy files there. (**edit** I think the entire `/run` filesystem is kept around)

**edit** - I found a couple articles by Rob Landley that add some more color to the process.  They all suggest the contents of the initramfs root does get destroyed/deleted.

> What switch_root does is delete all the files out of rootfs (to free up the memory) and then chroot into a new filesystem and exec a new init process out of the new filesystem.

> initramfs is rootfs: you can neither pivot_root
> rootfs, nor unmount it.  Instead delete everything out of rootfs to
> free up the space (find -xdev / -exec rm '{}' ';'), overmount rootfs
> with the new root (cd /newmount; mount --move . /; chroot .), attach
> stdin/stdout/stderr to the new /dev/console, and exec the new init

> Since initramfs is a
> ramfs, deleting its contents frees up the memory it uses.

**Links**

- https://landley.net/writing/rootfs-programming.html
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt
- https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/2dade4f18a86d05642aa6f3ef4c5b5100fd10907/util-linux/switch_root.c#L298
- https://www.michael-joost.de/linux_initramfs.html
- [Is it possible to access the initrd file system after boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884072/is-it-possible-to-access-the-initrd-file-system-after-boot)
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingCasper
- https://wiki.debian.org/InitramfsDebug
- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/initramfs-tools.8.html

Comment: It is mainly about debug the casper script. I generated some log files and dumped some binary files to / during /init.  /run seems a good place. Thanks